# How to do incremental load in Power BI using Web api connection?

Tags: api, datasource, powerbi, dashboard

I am trying to build real time dashboard using Web source (api call), I did set up the connection and it is working fine for the new data feed.

How to store this data feed to different table (24 hours history to show on dashboard) and keep appending new records from the API call to refresh tiles on dashboard?

Comment: lookup slowly changing dimensions.
However, I don't think you can do it exclusively in Power BI. You will need to load the data into a database to power BI. Possibly using SSAS in between

Comment: @Intern87 using database would be a second option but i am curious if anyone know the functionality to do it using M in Power BI. Thanks...